# Approaches for handling common data in ASP.NET MVC 3 views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm struggling with what would seem to be a very simple concept. If I have a value in the ViewBag intended for use by my _Layout.cshtml, how and where do I set that value?

Here are the most obvious (to me) options as I currently see them:

1. Set the value in each controller (not DRY)
2. Create my own controller base inheriting from Controller and set the value in the base class
3. Set the value in Global.asax.cs (feels dirty)
4. Create an ActionFilter to set the data and register the filter globally (also feels wrong)
5. Set the value in _ViewStart.cshtml (feels VERY wrong and VERY dirty)

For example:

**_Layout.cshtml**

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
       <h1>Welcome @ViewBag.UserName</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
       @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If each controller sets the UserName value, that's not terribly DRY. If I were tackling this with something like CodeIgniter, I'd just create my own base controller to handle these common items and go about my merry way. Is there a more preferred option with ASP.NET MVC 3?

Comment: well actually, in this particular scenario - im guessing "UserName" would actually come from the session/forms auth ticket. So you might want to use a HTML helper which uses FormsAuth code to grab the Username out of the cookie and render out a MvcHtmlString - just a thought...

Comment: Hmmm... good point. Maybe @ViewBag.UserName isn't the best example. I'm really more concerned with the bigger picture at the moment, though.

Comment: @RPM1984: it shouldn't matter to the view that the "UserName" came from form auth. It should be passed in (ViewBag or otherwise). The view should never "fetch" anything. Consider testing scenarios as well, you want to pass in fake data to the view to unit test.Not possible if your view is "fetching" things. Also pretty much invalidates the whole point of MVC pattern.Not picking on you, but I've just seen this type of mentality repeated in various MVC articles (including the default MVC project template!)

Comment: @rogerh - i agree with you in principle about the Views should be dumb and not "fetch" anything. However, a HTML helper reading the Forms Auth info is not "fetching" anything. To me, "fetching" something is a database call or a call to an external service. The UserName exists in the Http Context, much like the route values which is what the HTML/URL helpers work off, so i don't think your point in valid in this scenario. You can still unit test - by mocking the Http Context - same way you unit test any HTML helper.

Comment: @RPM1984: If the view isn't reading data from the model, it is fetching it. Simple as that. There are lots of things available in a view such as context, cookies, route data, etc. I wish it wasn't because it tempts people to do exactly what you describe. What if I don't just want the user's name, but his UserID? Or the last date he logged in? Or whether the user is male or female? I'm going to dump this in a cookie, or in HttpContext.Items[]? Why use a model at all? Why not just put everything into some random HttpContext value? Do you see what I'm trying to illustrate?

Comment: @rogerh. nope, not really. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Common view model and base controller is the way to go IMO.  Use a common view model as the base class for all of your view models.  Use the OnActionExecuted method in the base controller to get the view model (for an action returning a view) and cast it to the common view model.  Set the common properties at that time.

Comment: Groovy. Glad to know I'm not completely off base.

Comment: I know only the Sith deal in absolutes, but this is the only correct answer. The view is only supposed to read from the model, and only the controller can write to the model. If you are sticking to strong typed models you'll want a base model as well as a base controller.

Comment: @tvanfossen. This is an interesting approach and I am currentl trying it out. One question - can I use an ActionFilter instead of a base controller and hook into the `OnActionExecuted`? I need to pass common data but only on specific actions and so thought decoratin those with a filter would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I want to have ViewBag.PageHeight have a default value of 1000 for all pages but then allow that to be overridden by any page/view.  This is what I put in the _Layout.cshtml:

The page height is @(ViewBag.PageHeight ?? 1000)

This seems to work.